# Magento 2: why we need to use jquery widget($.widget)

Tags: magento2

i just want to know about why we need to use jquery widget($.widget) in script because we can also use the script without this jquery widget for requireJS.

any idea, please share.

Answer (score 0):

The require() function is AMD's mechanism for specifying and loading dependencies; therefore, we can add one to our app.js file to load the necessary files. The following loads jQuery UI's autocomplete widget.

```
 require([ "jquery-ui/autocomplete" ], function( autocomplete ) {
   ...
 });
```

When this code executes, RequireJS asynchronously loads jquery-ui/autocomplete.js as well as its dependencies: jQuery core (jquery.js), jQuery UI core (jquery-ui/core.js), the widget factory (jquery-ui/widget.js), the position utility (jquery-ui/position.js), and the menu widget (jquery-ui/menu.js).

All widgets built with the widget factory expose their constructor function when required with AMD; therefore we can use them to instantiate widgets on elements.
to understand more about it follow below link

[jquery widget](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/)